# cannot open manage.py after installing django

Tags: python, django, virtual, anaconda, manage.py

I have a problem in setting up django.

My situation: I have Anaconda Python 2.7 in my Windows 8 computer. On the Anaconda command prompt window, I type: `pip install django`. This is successful.

Then I create a folder named "newproject". On the command prompt I went to the folder "newproject". Then `django-admin.py startproject newproject`. This is successful.

Then I run `python manage.py runserver`. It tells me

```
"...can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

I checked out udemy django installation guide and other guides on the net. I have even set up a virtual environment. But the main problem is always: `can't open file 'manage.py'`

Comment: run the command on the directory where manage.py file exists.

Comment: You should run the command by changing the directory inside the newproject. It should work after that

Answer (score 23):

You're not in the proper directory...In the case you described, you should have:

1. `mkdir newproject` (not sure why you're doing this...but we'll continue with it)
2. `cd newproject`
3. `django-admin.py startproject newproject`
4. `cd newproject` ← A key missing part from what you did. You need to change into the directory where *manage.py* resides. Verify it by using `ls` at the command prompt after switching into the directory.
5. `python manage.py runserver`

Use `ls` often, if you need, to double check where you are in the directory tree.

Comment: Yes, OP need to check which directory OP is in while running the startproject command. The command creates start project folder in that directory. And then, as pointed by you, manage.py can be found in this newly created folder.

Answer (score 5):

**You are not in the correct directory**. You need to do **cd newproject** and the execute your **runserver** command.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was because the manage.py didn't get created and the problem was that:

In windows instead of typing "django-admin.py" just type "django-admin" and it will create the manage.py file

Answer (score 3):

you need to change your directory to the directory of the project.

1. open your environment by typing `activate environment_name`
2. change the directory to the folder in which you want to create the
   project by `cd Folder_Name`
3. then create your project by `django-admin startproject
   Project_Name`
4. then change the directory to your project folder
5. if you also want to create an app then type`python manage.py
   startapp App_name`
6. to confirm if it works type `python manage.py runserver`, then
   you should get a link in the terminal. copy and paste that link in
   the browser and you should see a successful page.

Comment: This is the answer. The reason many people face this problem is, some tutorials give wrong examples, ignoring "cd newproject" after startproject step.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this problem is because you're in the first project directory "parent directory", and you have to go to your project "newproject" that has the manage.py file.

**The way to this is simple:**

1. cd "name of your project", E.g. cd newproject
2. python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a `.` after you create the project.

Eg: `django-admin.py startproject newproject .`

This will allow you to run `python manage.py runserver` from where you are.

Answer (score 1):

That can happen because manage.py doesn't have permissions. 
Check the existence of manage.py throughout newproject, If exist you can fix it with:

```
$cd newproject
$chmod +x manage.py
```

Finally, try to execute `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, when Windows 10 changed credentials, Docker lost the access to drives. The fix for this issue, I  reset the credentials in docker-desktop > shared Drives > reset credentials at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

here is the solution

step 1: command ->  django-admin startproject project_name

step 2: command -> cd project_name

step 3: command -> python manage.py startapp app_name

try it may fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should navigate to the inner directory where your manage.py resides. For example:
If you have created projectname as
Django-admin startproject loginapp

**Step 1:** Go to loginapp 
**Step 2:** Click on it 
**Step 3:** You will find another loginapp and manage.py folder inside that 
**Step 4:** Use this rootpath commandprompt 
**Step 5:** Enter py manage.py runserver 
Now it will work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error seller. But this is what I discovered

1: open your terminal in your project environment

2: install Django using: pip install django  (if you are on windows)

3: then create your Django project using : django-admin startproject  newproject  . (django-admin start-project followed by project name give a space and add period (.) )
So it goes like this

django-admin startproject new project .

The period/fullstop (.) At the end tells djando the area in which the file should be created which is inside the project file its self you are working on. After this is done you are free to go. You can now run your server and enjoy

Run server using: python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put a period at the end of your command e.g
Django-admin startproject new project .

The period at the end (.) will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

02/2023
After CD to the project folder, I copy the command 'python manage.py runserver' command and enter. But the error still appears.

Solution:

Type 'mana' and use the **tab** to auto-complete the filename in the folder.

Answer (score -1):

There could be invalid interpreter selected .Try selecting the proper interpreter

Comment: Elaborate what you mean by selecting the proper interpreter pls