# Why docker-compose don't copy files to virtualbox machine when running? "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory."]

Tags: django, docker, django-models, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have problem with my dockers and I don't know why it happens.
I created docker-machine with this command:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-share-folder $(pwd) dev
```

Now, I run docker-compose from django-cookiecutter template:

```
docker-compose -f local.yml build
```

and then

```
docker-compose -f local.yml up
```

From this moment I have that error from django:

```
...

django_1    | PostgreSQL is available
django_1    | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
project_django_1 exited with code 2
```

Also when I used

```
docker-compose -f local.yml exec <here_id_container> django sh
```

to check if any files are there, folder app is empty.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/1689 ? If it wont help, please attach the result of `docker-compose -f local.yml (...) logs`

Comment: Or check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131744/cannot-open-manage-py-after-installing-django or https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/756/